# Average Response Time to Emails

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of emails in a database, they are broken into threads, so the below dataframe would represent a single conversation. I am trying to calculate the average response time for both me, as well as the person responding.

Currently I am doing this via a a loop, which seems woefully inefficient. Are there any functions available that I am not using that I could be? Could I potentially find a way to filter down to just unique responses? This would let me just shift the times and calculate the differences that way.

Sample Dataframe. As seen below, there could be multiple emails by 1 party before a response. Only the first should be used to calculate the response time difference

```
Sender    DateTime
Me        ISO8601
Me        ISO8601
Customer  ISO8601
Me        ISO8601
Customer  ISO8601
Customer  ISO8601
Me        ISO8601
Me        ISO8601
Me        ISO8601
Customer  ISO8601
```

Pseudo code of current operation (way too long to put the full actual code)

```
# Track who responded last
last_comment_type = None
# Track response numbers (number of times each party responded)
customer_response_count = 0
my_response_count = 0


# Determine who the first sender is (doesn't always have to be me)
if df.ix[df.index.values.min()]['ResponseType'] == customer:
    last_comment_type = 'Customer'
    next_response = df.iloc[1:][df['ResponseType'] = 'Me']
    my_total_response_time += next_response - row
    my_response_count += 1
else:
    last_comment_type = 'Me'
    next_response = df.iloc[1:][df['ResponseType'] = 'Customer']
    customer_total_response_time += next_response - row
    customer_response_count += 1

# Loop over rest of rows and figure out who responded to who.
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.ResponseType == 'Customer' and last_comment_type == 'Me':
        next_response = df[df.index > row.Index][df['ResponseType'] != 'Customer']
        my_total_response_time += next_response - row 
        my_response_count += 1
    if row.ResponseType == 'Me' and last_comment_type == 'Customer':        
        next_response = df[df.index > row.Index][df['ResponseType'] != 'Me']
        customer_total_response_time += next_response - row     
        customer_response_count += 1    

my_response_avg = my_total_response_time/my_response_count
customer_response_avg = customer_total_response_time/customer_response_count
```

Comment: What do the date / time stamps look like?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Given the thread in your data, do you just want to calculate the difference between the first message and the first response? Or for each thread calculate the difference between each interaction?

Comment: @ASGM In your answer below you have the right format. Its ISO 8601.

Comment: @user3471881 Apologies for the lack of clarity, it is as you sated in your first assumption. Difference between the first message and the first response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Pandas can do this much more simply.  If you just want to calculate the difference between the first messages:

```
df['block'] = ((df.Sender != df.Sender.shift()).cumsum())
mean_response_time = df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime'].diff().mean()
```

If you want to calculate the mean response time by `Sender`, you can use `groupby()`:

```
df['response_time'] = df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime'].diff()
gr = df.groupby('Sender').response_time
mean_response_times = gr.sum() / gr.count()
```

*Note: I use sum/count instead of mean because of [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5724) with `groupby` and `mean()`, which may be patched in the future.*

---

Let's break it down.  First we'll need a sample dataframe with usable times (which is what I'd recommend you provide in a question like this):

```
times = pd.date_range('10/18/2018', periods=8, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sender': ['A','B','A','A','B','B','B','A'], 'DateTime': times})
```

This gives you a dataframe like this:

```
             DateTime Sender
0 2018-10-18 00:00:00      A
1 2018-10-18 01:00:00      B
2 2018-10-18 02:00:00      A
3 2018-10-18 03:00:00      A
4 2018-10-18 04:00:00      B
5 2018-10-18 05:00:00      B
6 2018-10-18 06:00:00      B
7 2018-10-18 07:00:00      A
```

`df['block'] = ((df.Sender != df.Sender.shift()).cumsum())` creates a new column where sequential rows from the same `Sender` have the same number:

```
             DateTime Sender  block
0 2018-10-18 00:00:00      A      1
1 2018-10-18 01:00:00      B      2
2 2018-10-18 02:00:00      A      3
3 2018-10-18 03:00:00      A      3
4 2018-10-18 04:00:00      B      4
5 2018-10-18 05:00:00      B      4
6 2018-10-18 06:00:00      B      4
7 2018-10-18 07:00:00      A      5
```

Since all we care about (in version 1) is the time between the first message from one `Sender` to the time of the first message from the next sender, we can drop all rows but the first that have a duplicate value for `block`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime']
```

That gives us the times of each first message in each `Sender`-specific block:

```
0   2018-10-18 00:00:00
1   2018-10-18 01:00:00
2   2018-10-18 02:00:00
4   2018-10-18 04:00:00
7   2018-10-18 07:00:00
```

If we want the average time across all senders, all we need to do is add `diff()` and `mean()` to get the average time between rows:

```
df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime'].diff().mean()
```

Which gives:

```
Timedelta('0 days 01:45:00')
```

If we want the get the average time *by* sender, you need an extra step.  We make a new column for the response times, then group these by senders, then calculate the mean.

```
df['response_time'] = df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime'].diff()
gr = df.groupby('Sender').response_time
mean_response_time = gr.sum() / gr.count()
```

The result is:

```
Sender
A   02:00:00
B   01:30:00
```

---

**Note:** if you wanted to calculate the difference between the last message by one sender and the first message by the next sender:

```
df['block'] = ((df.Sender != df.Sender.shift()).cumsum())
df['last_message'] = df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='last')['DateTime']
df['first_message'] = df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime'].shift(-1)
mean_response_time = (df['first_message'].shift(-1) - df['last_message']).mean()
```

Comment: @AGSM Firstly, apologies for not constructing the dataframe, lesson learnt! It may take me a while to digest this. So it seems I was sort of on the right track with the shift idea, I just had no idea how to filter it down. Really smart idea on the assigning a number then just reducing the duplicates. I have so much to learn in pandas!!

As to your note, that is interesting, as it is quite close to what I need to add. Basically if the chain isn't finished I will do now() - last_message_time. If the chain is complete, I just leave it.

Comment: Apparently I cannot spell, I meant ASGM :)

Comment: Ok, so reading over this a bit, i think the only difference I have is that id need to know the average on both sides, say Average Response Time for Me and Average Response Time for !Me.  
  
My guess is I can just use:  
  
     `df.drop_duplicates('block', keep='first')['DateTime']` 
  
And split them off in pairs of two? As with the reduction you made it should always go A,B or B,A?

Edit: This would be the first message by one sender to the first message by the next sender.

Comment: I've extended the answer to cover the case of finding the time by sender.